# How can I optimize this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How I can optimize this code can run in O(n) for assign value in @TollPrice :

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT TollPrice
            FROM Car_TaxInfo
            WHERE (car_subgrp_id = @Kind) AND (Sal = @Sal)))
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @TollPrice = TollPrice
        FROM   Car_TaxInfo
        WHERE     (car_subgrp_id = @Kind) AND (Sal = @Sal)
        SET @IsExistToll = 1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @IsExistToll = 0
    END
```

Comment: Remove the if exists, just select the value and check @@rowcount after it. Also, check that there are correct indexes in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to verify for existence here:

```
SET @TollPrice = NULL --this is mandatory. If @TollPrice contains some value then it will retain that value after below statement if there will be no matching rows.

SELECT  @TollPrice = TollPrice
FROM    Car_TaxInfo
WHERE   (car_subgrp_id = @Kind) AND (Sal = @Sal)

IF @TollPrice IS NOT NULL
   SET @IsExistToll = 1
ELSE
   SET @IsExistToll = 0
```

If `TollPrice` can be `NULL` itself then you can use `@@ROWCOUNT`

```
SELECT  @TollPrice = TollPrice
FROM    Car_TaxInfo
WHERE   (car_subgrp_id = @Kind) AND (Sal = @Sal)

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
   SET @IsExistToll = 1
ELSE
   SET @IsExistToll = 0
```

Even more, you can do the following:

```
SET @IsExistToll = 0

SELECT  @TollPrice = TollPrice, @IsExistToll = 1
FROM    Car_TaxInfo
WHERE   (car_subgrp_id = @Kind) AND (Sal = @Sal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your system a OLAP system or PLTP one?
if it is OLAP or it is OLTP with acceptable amount of INSERT/UPDATE/Delete you may want to add index for car_subgrp_id  and Sal column.
In IF select clause you may combine your query with TOP 1 and replace EXISTS with this new query. I mean your new query may looks like this:

```
Declare @tPrice INT
IF (SELECT TOP 1 @tPrice=TollPrice
        FROM Car_TaxInfo
        WHERE (car_subgrp_id = @Kind) AND (Sal = @Sal) IS NOT NULL)
    SET @IsExistToll = 1
ELSE
    SET @IsExistToll = 0
```